# Firebase - doc exists but doc.exists returns false

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to test whether a document exists with title uid. I have confirmed that the document exists in Firestore within the users collection, but doc.exists always returns false. Note that my document uid contains only collections (no fields).

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var uid = user.uid
            db.collection("users").doc(uid)
              .get()
              .then((doc) => {
                console.log(doc)
                if (doc.exists) {
                  console.log('returning user')
                } else {
                  console.log('new user')
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
          } else {
            // User is signed out.
            // ...
          }
```

Comment: does your `console.log(doc)` print anything?

Comment: Yes it prints a documentSnapshot object with exists property set to false

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because while you had created collections within the document, you never created the document itself. You can tell whether documents exist because if they dont they will show up in Firestore as italics.

Comment: Thank God for this answer, I've been stuck for hours

Comment: How can I do that? I want my document id to be uid of user to organize all data. How can I achieve this?